Cable shield connection to metal enclosure on rolling stock
It's standard practice to ground cable shields at both ends to prevent EMC issues.  I am uncertain if this practice applies to enclosures installed on train roofs.
In my setup, I have an I/O cable connecting a device on the roof to a metal enclosure going to an internal device. The enclosure is internally connected to the signal ground and is galvanically tied to the vehicle's body as depicted in the following drawing.

My concern is that during a high-voltage incident on the enclosure from overhead line drops or transients, connecting the cable shield to the enclosure could create a path for high voltage to enter the vehicle. On the other hand, not connecting the cable shield could result in EMC issues.
While there is protection for such incidents for the train body, and as the enclosure is connected to it, this protection should extend to my device. This depends on the vehicle's protection reaction to the incident. If the reaction is not prompt, it could cause damage to the device inside the vehicle where the other end of the I/O cable is connected.
I'd appreciate any advice on the best approach to handle this situation.

This sounds like a problem where the resolution is not electrical, but functional, business, or contractual:

Is your device expected to withstand such a hit, a high-voltage strike?  (Notice an overhead line is orders of magnitude worse than any ESD or mains surge.)
Is the grounding expected to fail -- should it be considered unreliable?  For either box?
Is it at all feasible to design your product to withstand the full common-mode voltage (lifted ground, high voltage strike, plus EMI)?

It's my understanding, equipment for rolling stock is generally by agreement between parties; it seems like this is a step that should go back to the drawing board, to get weigh-in from the customer.
Perhaps resolution is simpler than that: maybe it was discussed by others, and this particular topic wasn't relayed to you specifically.  Maybe it wasn't discussed and defaults to applicable standards (do you have copies of them available?).  I don't know, but in any case it sounds like something your manager or contact can provide.

Thanks, @Tim. I've received this question directly from a client. The device is designed to comply with EN 50121-3-2 and has passed tests for ESD, EFT, and Surges. But the impact from overhead wires appears to exceed the device's capabilities and isn't addressed by the standard.
Their concern is that if such a strike happens out of the blue, there is no way for the cable to carry the current back inside the vehicle.
My other suggestion might be to not use a shielded cable, which in turn will increase the risk of EMI, however running the cable in less noisy area might help? I don't know.

Well, there's nothing noisier than ten thousand volts arcing to your chassis.  Cable or not, doesn't exactly matter, if it's melted into a puddle. I'm not aware of standard solutions for this particular concern, but it sounds unusual to me. I might suggest proceeding with design as requested, updating the quoted price and project timeline to reflect the more... aggressive countermeasures required. If the updated quote doesn't snap them out of the ask -- well, I guess that's one highly reliable piece of equipment you're going to deliver!

Don't forget to include cost of testing and verification; you may need to engage the services of a power generator or lightning test facility to deliver that kind of sustained voltage and current.

Thanks @Tim, I agree this is so unusual.
